# A question about s-t cuts in graph theory and their reverse.

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let's have a directed graph $G=(V,E)$. If I pick some vertex to be the source $s$ and the some other vertex to be the sink $t$, I can calculate the max flow allowable on the graph from $s$ to $t$ using the known max flow/min cut algorithms.

Is there an analogous argument to finding a few related things:
1) the cut that minimizes the quantity min(s->t max flow, t->s max flow)? This would seem to me to be just two applications of max flow/min cut, and taking the smaller one; is this more subtle?
2) the cut that minimizes the sum of the s->t max flow and the t->s max flow? Is there also some efficient way of doing this, or does this turn into some hard joint optimization problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just reflect the graph across $t$ to make a larger graph and run the same algorithm? You would still have $s$ as the source but your sink would be the copy of $s$ on the other side of $t$.

Comment: That seems to me to work, don't see any subtleties that can arise. If you would like, please feel free to re-enter your comment as an answer. Thanks!